# Confused about std::runtime_error vs. std::logic_error

Tags: c++, boost, stl, exception

I recently saw that the boost program_options library throws a `logic_error` if the command-line input was un-parsable.  That challenged my assumptions about `logic_error` vs. `runtime_error`.

I assumed that logic errors (`logic_error` and its derived classes) were problems that resulted from internal failures to adhere to program invariants, often in the form of illegal arguments to internal API's.  In that sense they are largely equivalent to ASSERT's, but meant to be used in released code (unlike ASSERT's which are not usually compiled into released code.) They are useful in situations where it is infeasible to integrate separate software components in debug/test builds or the consequences of a failure are such that it is important to give runtime feedback about the invalid invariant condition to the user.

Similarly, I thought that `runtime_error`s resulted exclusively from runtime conditions outside of the control of the programmer: I/O errors, invalid user input, etc.

However, program_options is obviously heavily (primarily?) used as a means of parsing end-user input, so under my mental model it certainly should throw a `runtime_error` in the case of bad input.

Where am I going wrong?  Do you agree with the boost model of exception typing?

Comment: Why don't you ask this question on the boost users mailing list?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In this case, I think (at least for the most part) you're right and it's wrong. The standard describes `logic_error` as:

> The class logic_error defines the type of objects thrown as exceptions to report errors presumably detectable before the program executes, such as violations of logical preconditions or class invariants.

A command line argument that can't be parsed doesn't seem to fit that very well.

By contrast, it describes `runtime_error` as:

> The class runtime_error defines the type of objects thrown as exceptions to report errors presumably detectable only when the program executes.

That seems to be a better fit.

Comment: My key phrase here is `detectable only`. If the error was induced by an external input beyond your control, then it is `runtime_error`. Relatively speaking,  the required settings variables during initialization is within your control.

Answer (score 9):

From a pure standard point of view, you are right. program_options should throw classes derived from either `runtime_error` or `logic_error` depending on whether the error is runtime or logical. (I did not review the current code to determine such idea classification for current exceptions).

From a practical standpoint, I have yet to see C++ code that makes useful decisions based on whether exception is `logic_error` or `runtime_error`. After all, the only reason you would throw a `logic_error` as opposed to letting assert file is if you want to try recover somehow, and that's not different from recovery from a runtime error. Personally, I view `logic_error` vs. `runtime_error` the same way as checked exceptions in Java -- theoretically nice, but not useful in practice. Which means, that maybe, I'll just make `program_options::error` derive from `exception`. That is, when I'll find that 'spare time' everybody keeps talking about.

Comment: I believe that you should let the logic_error go and terminate the program (so that the victim can then send the debug/core information to developers), while runtime_error should be catched and report: "you gave me un-parsable information, please try again."

Answer (score 8):

The current draft of the C++0x Standard says (clause 19.2):

> 1) In the error model reflected in
>   these classes (i.e. the exception types), errors are divided into
>   two broad categories: logic errors and
>   runtime errors.
>
> 2) The distinguishing characteristic
>   of logic errors is that they are due
>   to errors in the internal logic of the
>   program. In theory, they are
>   preventable.
>
> 3) By contrast, runtime errors are due
>   to events beyond the scope of the
>   program. They cannot be easily
>   predicted in advance.

Together with the quotes cited in one of the other answers this explains why Boost.ProgramOptions throws a std::logic_error for preventable errors caused by an 'error presumably detectable before the program executes'.

Comment: By your logic, if the user passed in an argument containing a path to a non-existent file, the application should throw a logic error in response to the file-not-found runtime error since the argument to the application, created before the application started, was provably incorrect.  I don't buy that.

Comment: Well, actually it's not my logic. I gave you quotes from the Standard. Obviously, there is no sharp destinction possible between both types of errors, and wrong user input is one of those 'gray zones'.

Comment: This would pivot on whether the program can be reasonably expected to check/sanitize the relevant type of input. If such an expectation is unreasonable, it is beyond the scope of the program. But the "scope" is defined as the library code's expectations, not your program's design.

Comment: I think by “error presumably detectable before the program executes” what's intended is “detectable by sufficiently carefully reading the program source code”.

Answer (score 0):

The user could verify that the file exists, run the program, and suddenly learn that the file has been deleted. That's why an I/O problem is always a `runtime_error`. Stateful problems are runtime_errors, even if the caller could have checked, since another thread could cause the problem.

`logic_error` is when the arguments to a function are wrong. It is *only* for things which could have been caught earlier with stronger type-checking.

So, "missing file" is a `runtime_error`, but "improperly formatted filename" is a `logic_error`.

Technically, a logical error *within* a function is a `logic_error` too, but if you're smart enough to test for it inside your own function, you should be smart enough to prevent it in the first place.

Comment: "if you're smart enough to test for it inside your own function, you should be smart enough to prevent it in the first place" - this makes a lot of assumptions, including that you have control over all the code

Comment: There are 3 domains: 1) the caller of your function, 2) your function, and 3) the libraries called by your function. If (1) calls (2) with bad input, (2) should throw `logic_error`. If something went wrong that (1) could not test for (e.g. a file is suddenly deleted by another process), (2) should throw `runtime`. That's clear, right? But what happens if (2) calls (3) improperly? That's a logical error caused by (2), so (3) could throw `logic`. I'm saying if (2) traps a `logic` thrown by (3), (2) should re-throw as a `runtime`, but it's better not to cause the error in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

IMO,

- `std::logic_error` is thrown by a user C++ program *logic* intentionally. Predicted by a user program.
- `std::runtime_error` is thrown by a C++ *runtime* (or core part of the langauge…) to abstract lower level errors. Just happens without any intention without involving of any user code.