# What type of std::exception should be thrown when reading a file of incorrect format?

Tags: c++, exception, std

Just wondering if there is any agreement on what type of std::exception is appropriate to throw when parsing a file with incorrect format in C++. I would say a generic `std::logic_error` even though it's not the logic but data what is wrong, what do you guys think it should be?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error states "It reports errors that are a consequence of faulty logic within the program". Therefore I think it is inappropriate for an unexpected file layout, as that's beyond the control of your program.

Comment: you can throw a custom exception and document it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering [Standard C++ exceptions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception), i would say *runtime_error* fits this case the best.

> std::runtime_error
>
> It reports errors that are due to events beyond the scope of the program and can not be easily predicted.

Parsing a file requires runtime resources (the file itself and its content are only determined during runtime). [0]

However defining a new exception (for example: call it *file_error* and derive it from *std::runtime_error*) is another reasonable approach i think. This way you can extend the exception's capabilities so your software will be able to deal with the occurring problems more easily. (You can add any functionality to an exception class that a standard class is able to have.)

It is possible to throw any object (from any class) as an exception but deriving custom exceptions from std::exception is considered good practice, because it fits well into STL's and third party's exception handling methods (in most of the time).

I personally prefer using my own exceptions.

Also read similar question: [SO:Confused about std::runtime_error vs. std::logic_error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924058/confused-about-stdruntime-error-vs-stdlogic-error)

[0]: In case you logically connect the **file system** (and the file in it) to the **operating system** then you might consider using *system_error* for this case - but parsing it doesn't seem like this category.

Answer (score 0):

You are not limited to throwing std exceptions. Any class can be thrown as an exception. In large applications you will typically find entire classes whose only purpose is for an instance of them to get thrown as an exception, so that when it's caught, the exception handler has more information and context available for it to decide the next course of action (that was, of course, prepared and placed into the class instance before it was thrown).

Comment: Everything you say is true, but there's no good reason not to *derive* your custom exception class from `std::exception` or one of its subclasses.